# Rails alias_attribute not working in RSPEC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

In Shop Model:

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  alias_attribute :token, :basic_token
  # basic_token column is set NOT to be NULL in DB
end
```

In Shop Factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :shop do
    basic_token '12313123123123123123123'
    ...
    ...
  end
end
```

In RSPEC Shops Controller:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ShopsController, type: :controller do
  before do
    @shop = create(:shop) # FAILS

    => Failure/Error: @shop = create(:shop)
    => ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
    => PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "basic_token" violates not-null constraint

  end

  describe "" do
     ........
  end
end
```

**Rails Console tests:**

```
   WITH alias_attribute:
    (byebug) @shop = build(:shop)
    #<Shop remote_id: 1110212666, domain: "abc.myshopify.com", basic_token: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, ... >

    (byebug) @shop.valid?
    true

    (byebug) @shop.errors.messages
    {}

  WITH alias_attribute commented (# alias_attribute :token, :basic_token):
    (byebug) @shop = build(:shop)
    #<Shop remote_id: 1110212666, domain: "abc.myshopify.com", basic_token: "12313123123123123123123", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, ... >

    (byebug) @shop.valid?
    true
    (byebug) @shop.errors.messages
    {}
```

Commenting `alias_attribute :token, :basic_token`, and it works.

Any idea why I can't make the record with `alias_attribute`?

Note that this works in development || production environment, only getting error in testing.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you do `@shop = build(:shop)`, then inspect the `@shop` record? What are its attributes? What is `@shop.valid?`? What is `@shop.errors.messages`? And what is the database schema, for the `shops` table?

Comment: `RAILS_ENV=test bin/rake db:migrate`

Comment: @TomLord i added rails console test results, as you asked.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko i tried, but same error exists.

Comment: Can you reproduce that on a vanilla rails app? I suspect there's something else in your code that causes the error, which you haven't found (or shown us).

Comment: For example, maybe there's *something else* (e.g. in the `FactoryBot` definition) that sets `token = nil`, and this only impacts the `basic_token` when the alias is present?

Answer (score 0):

On a basic model with just one attribute, one alias, and a factory with the same default, I don't get this behaviour (with RSpec, Factory Girl, Rails 5.1). Providing the rest of the factory and the model would help.

To find the origin of the bug, you can:

1. Comment out the whole Shop model except the `alias_attribute`
2. Comment out the whole factory except the `basic_token`
3. Check that a dummy test that just does `create(:shop)` passes
4. Uncomment commented lines batch by batch, running the test each iteration.

If step 3 above failed:
  5. Try changing the name of the alias, see if anything in your app conflicts with the name `token`
  6. Try `git bisect` as far as you can to find the guilty commit. Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for help, i tried your steps, and i can confirmed that only line for alias_attribute causes me the error, commenting it works everything fine. :(

Comment: Did you try git bisect?
Other idea: change the name of the alias, `dummy` instead of `token`, to see if there is any conflict with `token